# How to properly vectorize this Python function?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, numpy, for-loop, vectorization

I have the following problem. I want to vectorize one function which is currently iterating with iterrows and for loop to gain performance.

We are given one dataframe in for every person loop which looks like this (number of rows differs depending on person_name):

| Person_name | var_1 | var_2 | var_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | good | car_1 | train_2 |
| John | bad | car_1 | train_1 |

The loop looks like this:

```
for name in names:
    dataframe_user = dataframe[dataframe['Person_name']==name]
    empty_list = []
    
    for row in dataframe_user.iterrows():
        if row['var_1'] == 'good':
            empty_list.append('Thats good')
        elif row['var_1'] == 'bad' and row['var_2'] == 'car_1':
            empty_list.append('Not so bad')
        else:
            empty_list.append('Very bad')
```

I would like to vectorize both for loops. So essentially I would like to have code like:

```
vectorized_funct_name(names)
```

Vectorized_funct_name as the *for name in names* loop and which will trigger inside funct vectorized_rows which makes same thing like the *for row in dataframe_user.iterrows()* loop.

I already tried to vectorize the function using numpy vectorize function although it passess all cells instead of rows to the vectorized function.

I also tried to use Pandas apply and it worked although I'm seeking for the best performance available.

Thanks in advance for help and for reading.

Comment: The "empty_list" (which isn't empty anymore) containing strings doesn't seem like a good way to handle the information. Just `good = dataframe_user["var_1"] == "good"`, `not_so_bad = (dataframe_user["var_1"] == "bad") & (dataframe_user["var_2"] == "car_1")`, `bad = (good | not_so_bad) == False`.

Comment: @MikaelÖhman It seems like a good idea thanks! Have you got any further optimalization improvements? I'm sitting with it for a whole week and all mine ideas give only a few seconds improvement :/